# How to rewrite Oracle specific function TO_NUMBER to ANSI SQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ansi-sql

There is a legacy software running against an Oracle database. I'm trying to generalize it for Docker tests, so I prepared a PostgreSQL image with the database schema. Now I'm trying to run that application against the Postgres DB, but there is the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function to_number(text) does not exist
```

So I looked into the code and found the following construct in some selects:

```
to_number(to_char({0},'HH24MI')) <= to_number(to_char({1},'HH24MI'))
to_number(to_char({0},'HH24MI')) > to_number(to_char({1},'HH24MI'))
```

Since I'm not a database specialist, I assume that this `TO_NUMBER` is an Oracle-specific function. In this case it works as a filter to return records for the specified time range.

Is there a way how could I simply replace this `TO_NUMBER` function with some similar function in ANSI SQL?

Comment: `CAST(... AS INT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the Oraclism

```
to_number(to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH24MI'))
```

you could use this standard SQL construct:

```
100 * EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM current_timestamp)
    + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM current_timestamp)
```

Comment: Both solution works, even `CAST(... AS INT)` which looks more elegant. Since this is the only answer, I accept it. i must test the filter of course but I think will be OK.

Comment: If you want a standard SQL statement, you cannot use `to_char`. PostgreSQL happens to support it, but it is not standard.

Comment: You'd have to benchmark it. But my guess is that any performance difference is so small that it will vanish compared to the rest of the cost of the query, whatever the query is.